# Spring Kafka Consumer skips some offsets

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a very simple Kafka Consumer (v 2.6.2).
It is the only consumer in a consumer-group, and this group is the only one reading from a topic (with 6 partitions, and some 3 million events in it).
Broker is also version 2.6.x

As we need to fulfil a **"excatly-once"** scenario, we took a deep look, if we really consume every event exactly once that is written to the topic.
Unfortunately we found out that: **The consumer sometimes skips an offset, and sometimes even a bunch of offsets of a partition.**

The **Consumer** does not do much more than logging.
An Error-Handler is configured with logging.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}", topics = "${topicname}")
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, BlaBlaEvent> record) throws Exception {
  // mostly logging
}
```

And it logs:

```
consuming Offset=30 Partition=2
consuming Offset=31 Partition=2
consuming Offset=32 Partition=2
consuming Offset=67 Partition=2
```

(did you see the **Offset=67**?)

Here's our **application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_URL}
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol: SSL
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader=true

spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-type=PKCS12
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password=${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-password=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=${TRUSTSTORE_PATH}
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=${KEYSTORE_PATH}

spring.kafka.consumer.client-id=BlablaNotificationReader
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=blabla-group
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=none
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

logging.level.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG
```

### Sidenotes:

- Consumer runs in OpenShift v3.11 (Kubernetes 1.11). No pod restart or anything happened at that time.
- No errors in the log on broker-side, nor on consumer-side. just silent skipping.
- It happens about once a week

Does anyone have an idea how to find the root of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're looking for exactly-once semantics, you probably have transaction-enabled producers - if so, it might be due to the partitions having transactional records.

The `KafkaConsumer` [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) states:

*Partitions with transactional messages will include commit or abort markers which indicate the result of a transaction. There markers are not returned to applications, yet have an offset in the log. **As a result, applications reading from topics with transactional messages will see gaps in the consumed offsets.** These missing messages would be the transaction markers, and they are filtered out for consumers in both isolation levels. Additionally, **applications using read_committed consumers may also see gaps due to aborted transactions**, since those messages would not be returned by the consumer and yet would have valid offsets.*

The only way I see to actually miss a record would be if the consumer committed an offset for or after a record / records that didn't get processed for some reason.

If you want more information about the records being polled from the broker and the offsets being committed, you can set the logging level for the `org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer` class to `TRACE`. That should give you a good insight on the records being received and the offsets being committed. If all offsets *EDIT: before the one* being committed have been processed, it's not likely you're missing any.

In order to check if the `exactly-once` semantics are correct, maybe you can try to correlate the logs from your producers to the logs from your consumers through some id, specially when this event happens.

You might also want to check the producers' logs from when that happens, since the gap might be due to aborted transactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tomaz Fernandes for your answer.
1. Our producer is not transaction-enabled. So I guess our gaps can not be the markers. Also, the gaps are sometimes too large for this suspect (64 events), i guess... But interesting to hear that they also result in their own offsets in the log.
2. I am pretty sure the the missed offsets get not committed. I see the other commitment logs when running in DEBUG log-level.
3. Good point, I will set from DEBUG to TRACE right now
4. We do correlate the produced and consumed messages
5. No aborted Tx or Errors on Producer side in the logs

Comment: Other thoughts: 1. Any chance you may have another consumer running with the same group id? 2. Try to compare the number of records received as per the Spring Kafka logs to the next processed record's offset. It can't go from 32 to 67 without having received the intermediate records, unless some seek is taking place. Not sure I can be of more help, maybe try to update your question with some of the logs regarding records being polled, processed and committed. Or let's see if someone else has other ideas.

Comment: Hi @girafi, any luck there?

Comment: Hey @tomaz, unfortunately no informative news up to now. 1. no, no chance of another consumer in the same group. verified a hundred times :) 2. also with TRACE logs, the consumer commits the last offset (say 32), and then polls/receives the next which is really 67. Silence in between...
We are now continuiing our investigation.

Comment: Hi @girafi were you able to figure this out?